# droppable sensitive to draggables despite being on a different stack level

Tags: jquery, css, z-index, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

Imagine this very basic draggable/droppable setup:

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="dropArea"></div>
</div>
<div id="itemBox">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

`#dropArea` is the droppable.

`#itemBox > .item` are the draggables.

For some reason, the droppable reacts to the draggable, even the draggable has not even been dragged out of the `#itemBox`.

[See this fiddle for a live example](http://jsfiddle.net/tuM2M/).

I am kind of baffled by this although i am sure it is perfectly correct. It's simply my misunderstanding of how the draggable/droppable seems to behave, that lead me to this problem.

I tried appending the draggable to `body` as well as to the `#itemBox` but the effect remains the same. I also tried playing around with various `z-index` settings (giving the droppable a lower `z-index` than `#itemBox`) but to no avail.

Why is this happening and how can i avoid it? I need the droppable to react only once the draggable has actually left the `#itemBox`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the updated **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tuM2M/3/)**

Added droppable ability to itemBox and disabled dropArea when item is over itemBox.
Sample code:

```
$('#itemBox').droppable({
   hoverClass: 'dragHover',
   over:function(){
      $('#dropArea').droppable('disable').removeClass('ui-state-disabled dragHover');    
   },
   out:function(){
      $('#dropArea').droppable('enable').addClass('dragHover');
   }
});
```